# `sbt run` results in an error when compiling after adding dependencies

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ubuntu, sbt

I have added following dependencies to **built.sbt**, after running the `sbt run` in terminal, I got the bellow error:

```
$ sbt run
[info] welcome to sbt 1.5.5 (Private Build Java 1.8.0_292)
[info] loading global plugins from /home/hayat/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] loading project definition from /home/hayat/myproject/project
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to scala3-simple (in build file:/home/hayat/myproject/)
[info] Updating 
[info] Resolved  dependencies
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.spark:spark-streaming:3.1.2
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /home/hayat/.ivy2/localorg.apache.spark/spark-streaming/3.1.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming/3.1.2/spark-streaming-3.1.2.pom
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:258)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.$anonfun$update$38(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:227)
[error]     at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.update(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:227)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:60)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:59)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:133)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:73)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$20(LibraryManagement.scala:146)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:146)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:127)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChangedW$1(Tracked.scala:219)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:160)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask0$1(Defaults.scala:3678)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.spark:spark-streaming:3.1.2
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /home/hayat/.ivy2/localorg.apache.spark/spark-streaming/3.1.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming/3.1.2/spark-streaming-3.1.2.pom
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed Sep 16, 2021 11:21:30 AM
```

Here is  **built.sbt**:

```
val scala3Version = "3.0.2"

lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "scala3-simple",
    version := "0.1.0",

    scalaVersion := scala3Version,

    libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming" % "3.1.2",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core" % "3.1.2"
  )
```

- Scala version: 3.0.2
- Sbt version: 1.5.5

Comment: For information, `spark-streaming` depends on `spark-core` so you don't need to add `spark-core` in your dependency list if you already have `spark-streaming`. However, you may need `spark-sql` library as it contains the most common APIs for using Spark.

Comment: any dependency I try to add, it's give me such error

Comment: Spark is not compatible/available for Scala 3 yet.

Comment: @Gael J should I change to scala 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libraries `spark-streaming` and `spark-core` don't exist, it is `spark-streaming_2.12` and `spark-core_2.12`, where 2.12 is the Scala version. Currently there are no `spark-streaming_3.0` and `spark-core_3.0` libraries.

So to solve your issue, you need to:

- downgrade your version of scala from `3.0.2` to `2.12.x` (latest current version, `2.12.15`) as there is no version of Spark for Scala 3
- use `spark-streaming_2.12` library instead of `spark-streaming`
- use `spark-core_2.12` library instead of `spark-core`

To use `_2.12` version of libraries, you can either add `_2.12` to your library name:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.12" % "3.1.2",
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.12" % "3.1.2"
```

or, better, use `%%` between group and library name to automatically add scala version to library name:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "3.1.2",
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.1.2"
```

So your `build.sbt` should become:

```scala
val scala2Version = "2.12.15"

lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "scala2-simple",
    version := "0.1.0",

    scalaVersion := scala2Version,

    libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "3.1.2",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.1.2"
  )
```

Comment: but I have added this dependencies in IntelliJ in windows, it's working correctly

Comment: How did you add dependencies in IntelliJ ? Did you download jar file directly from maven repository (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming_2.12/3.1.2/) and add it in your project ?

Comment: Using the Scala 2.12 version of Spark in Scala 3 project won't work. I'd suggest you remove this piece of your answer @Vincent

Comment: @Vincent Doba I have added as same as above.

Comment: @GaëlJ I clarified that. It was at the end of my answer that Mustafa should use scala 2.12, but it seems it was not clear enough

Comment: @MustafaHayat if you didn't change any of SBT configuration, all `build.sbt` (within or outside intelliJ) will save retrieved librairies in the same local repository. So it means that if you have no problem in intelliJ, you should have no problem using SBT. I guess that librairies weren't actually retrieved by IntelliJ. You can check that by creating a scala file in your sbt project, in directory `/src/main/scala`, and type `import org.apache.spark` as the first line of this file. If some part of this line appears as red, it means the library wasn't actually retrieved.

Comment: @VincentDoba Thank you so much, it working correctly.  The problem was with the scala version